# jQuery security issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

I'm feeling scared about a solution i'm using in one of my app. 
Basically, i use this snippet :

```
var username = ...;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
    url: "getFeed.php",
    data: "username="+username,
    success: function(html) {
    // do the stuff         
    }
});
```

My question is : is this hackable ? If you use the chrome/firefox/... build-in code editor and replace `var username = ...` by `var username = 'user1';`, would it work ?

Thanks

Comment: yo can paste your code right into the console and press play

Comment: Maybe also use a token of some sort as well will improve your security.

Comment: Validation should always be done on server side (also)

Comment: I never trust values in javascript. Always verify server side if there's something that requires some level of security.

Comment: Also don't construct your data manually. Instead, pass an object literal to the `data` parameter: `data: { username: username }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, anyone with a javascript debugger will be able to change the variable to whatever username they want. JavaScript is always open to the user and can be modified easily.

Typically you would have a login page to authenticate the user (often cookie based), and then on every subsequent request (Ajax or otherwise) you would be able authenticate the cookie and make sure the user is who he says he is. This will however require a server side solution to the authentication.

Comment: Any type of data like this should be validated / secured server side not client side.

Comment: That's what i thought, i think i will go on server-sided security based with tokens, that was pretty obvious.